# Can two functions non differentiable at any point say 'a' form another function with their linear combination which is differentiable at 'a'

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider two functions $ f (x) $ and $g (x)$ such that at a point $'a'$ in their domain both of them are non differentiable because they are of indeterminate type, but for a function $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ is such that the the sum of their derivatives becomes a determinate form at $'a'$ [Eg if $f'(x)= \infty$ and $g'(x)=\infty$ but there difference is some constant ]. So will we call the function $h(x)$ differentiable at the point $'a'$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. If, for instance, $f(x)=g(x)=\sqrt x$, then both of them are non-differentiable at $0$. But if $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, then $h$ (which is the null function) *is* differentiable an $0$.